# Memory Deallocation of Dynamically Added Mesh Not Working

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, webgl, three.js

I have a **Mesh** instance which uses a **TubeGeometry** for it's path.  When I make changes to the underlying curve which the **TubeGeometry** instance is based on, I am removing the mesh from the scene and then creating a new one.

The scene updates fine, but the memory is exploding, which tells me I'm not deallocating the removed mesh correctly once it's off the scene.

Here's the code I'm trying to use to deallocate:

```
$.each(parent.children, function (idx, obj) {
  parent.remove(obj);
  renderer.deallocateObject(obj);
  obj.deallocate();
});
```

where `parent` is an **Object3D** that I place the **Mesh** in, and `renderer` is an instance of **WebGLRenderer**.

*Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to do this correctly?*

[Here's a **Plunk** with my currently example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/2pJcit?p=preview) Relevant code is in the **scene.js** file, lines 76-86.  Take note that the example is using **r53**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't deallocate the used geometry

```
$.each(parent.children, function (idx, obj) {
  parent.remove(obj);
  renderer.deallocateGeometry(obj.geometry);
  renderer.deallocateObject(obj);
  obj.geometry.deallocate();
  obj.deallocate();
});
```

Comment: `deallocateGeometry` is not a method in **r53** (the version in my example), and in the newly released **r54** all the `WebGLRenderer.deallocate*` methods are private.  Nevertheless, +1 for pointing out the lack of geometry deallocation, which does seem to be the issue.

Comment: Hopefully r54 will make things simpler. Just call `geometry.dispose()`/`texture.dispose()`/`material.dispose()`...